# Clarification on `this` keyword in a lambda

Tags: java, reactive-programming

```
interface Observable<T> {
    Subscription subscribe(Observer<T> observer);


    default Observable<T> filter(Predicate<T> fn) {
        return observer -> {
            Observer<T> obsT = new Observer<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(T t) {
                    if (fn.test(t))
                        observer.onNext(t);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    observer.onError(t);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    observer.onComplete();
                }
            };
            return this.subscribe(obsT);
        };
    }
}
```

What does `this` refer to in the above code,can someone please help...

Comment: In the given context, `this` refers to the surrounding object, i.e. the current instance of the `Observable<T>`-interface.

Comment: `this` here means the same thing it would mean outside of the lambda - the object to which `filter` method belongs. `this` also happens to be redundant here.

Comment: Downvoting because the question does not show effort. Please rewrite your exaplme so it meet requirements for [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

It tells the current `Observable` object instance to call its own `Subscribe` method after it gets done processing a `Filter` call and return the new `Subscription` as an `Observable`.

More specifically, `this` is a pointer to the object instance that is executing the current scope.

Comment: "*...`this` is a pointer...*" - There are no pointers in Java, only references.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is defined in [JLS §15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2):

> Unlike code appearing in anonymous class declarations, the meaning of names and the `this` and `super` keywords appearing in a lambda body, along with the accessibility of referenced declarations, are the same as in the surrounding context (except that lambda parameters introduce new names).

In plain english, this means that `this` references the current instance of the surrounding type. Thus, in your example, `this` references the current instace of `Observable<T>`.

This also means that you cannot use `this`, if the surrounding method is static:

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Sample {
  int x = 0;

  public static void main(String... args) {
    Supplier<String> function = () -> {
      return Integer.toString(this.x); // This is line 8
    };
  }
}
```

If you try to compile this code, the compiler will yield the following error:

```
Sample.java:8: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
      return Integer.toString(this.x);
                              ^
1 error
```

<kbd>[Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/rsbNjq)</kbd>

Comment: ,thanks for the lucid explanation.Just to reiterate, in the below scenario,
        someObservable.filter(x -> x % 2 == 0)    does the someObservable refer to the `this`

Comment: @Codershree `someObservable` references the object that was last assigned to `someObservable`...

Comment: So lets say i chain a map operation after my filter in this case, so it would mean that since the filter itself returns an Observable<Integer> so the current instance would point to the observable generated by the filter to which map would then subscribe to,Is my understanding correct.

Comment: @Codershree please refrain from asking new questions in comments and please limit yourself to one question per post, otherwise you may invalidate already existing answers. I cannot follow your train of thoughs. Create an example and I can take a look at it.